# DC Battery Charging Question

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, batteries, electrical-engineering

I have a 7.4v LiIon that hold 1450ma.  I have a variable DC bench power supply that I can crank up or down and adjust as needed.  I want to quickly charge the battery and noticed  if I adjust the power supply to 7.4V +-  I can only get 150 ma or so current out of the power supply.   If  push the Volts to7.8 I can get 300 am and the current keeps going up the more I increase the voltage.  How far can I push the battery to charge it quickly?  Could I use 9vdc to charge a 7.4vdc battery.  Note:  there is no circuitry unless inside the battery itself. I just attached probes from the supply to the battery.  Wish there was an easy way to make a cradle for the different pins on batteries- but that a different topic altogether.

[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an engineering SE question? The spec sheet for that battery might have charging information.

Rule of thumb: SAFELY trickle-charge at 1/10th of the amp-hours rating, so for example a 300mA-H battery is charged at 30mA for ten hours or more.  For RAPID charging, an algorithm or time-profile is used, and those designed for one manufacturer's products may destroy any slightly different batteries.

Yes, the supply-voltage during recharge is always higher than the battery quiescent voltage.